# Python tkinter simpledialog. How to bind a key to the OK button in simpledialog

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, bind, simpledialog

```
def prompt_new_name(self):
    new_name = simpledialog.askstring("Name Change", "New name")
    if new_name is not None:
        self.request_name_change(new_name)
```

I want to bind enter key on the keypad to the OK button in the simpledialog askstrinig prompt. (realized later normal enter key is already bound, but I need both enter keys to be bound)
I know how to bind enter key to a widget using bind function. However, to do that I need a reference to the widget.

For this case, I don't have the reference to the widget since I am calling askstring fuction on simpledialog without making the widget. I am wondering how I can achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDialog` is "simple". Create own dialog (using `TopLevel` widget) if you need something different.

---

Or see `SimpleDialog` source code to recreate `askstring`

https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.0/simpledialog_8py_source.html

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog 

class My_QueryString(tkinter.simpledialog._QueryString):

      def body(self, master):
          self.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.ok) # KeyPad Enter
          super().body(master)

def myaskstring(title, prompt, **kw):
    d = My_QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
    return d.result

#---------------------------------------------------------

root = tk.Tk()

new_name = myaskstring("Name Change", "New name")
if new_name:
    print(new_name)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that `<Return>` does not work so `<KP_Enter>` must be used. OTH, `<Escape>` **does** work and `<KP_Escape>` is undefined.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't understand your comment. OP asked how to use `KeyPad Enter`, not normal `Return` - and this is why I use `KP_Enter`. But code works for me even when I press `Return` (without binding). BTW there is no `KP_Escape` because `KP_` means `KeyPad` (numeric pad on right side of keyboard) which doesn't have key `Esc`

Comment: for over a year `<Return>` wasn't working for me in simple dialog and I tried changing all my modules around until I saw you key pad enter. Thanks for that!